# Semantic UI React Dropdown: Header Options?

Tags: semantic-ui-react

Is there a way to get a selection dropdown with header items in options?

I know of course there is this tag:

```
<Dropdown.Header icon='tags' content='Filter by tag' />
```

But this requires the whole dropdown to have custom Dropdown Items and does not work with Semantic UI's "selection" keyword that does a lot of dropdown management for me and let me give the options over an object array ("options").

When adding/ declaring my options I would like to be able to define it as a header item. Like this:

```
{
                key: id,
                value: id,
                text: name,
                content: (
                    <span>
                        {name}
                        <Label circular>{points}</Label>
                    </span>
                ),
                header: true
            }
```

Is there something like that? I can't find anything in the documentation.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [Dropdown](https://react.semantic-ui.com/modules/dropdown/) and manipulate the array like this:

```
const options = [
    {
        component:
            Dropdown.Menu,
        children:
            <Dropdown.Menu scrolling>
                <Dropdown.Header content='Filter by tag' />
                <Dropdown.Divider />
            </Dropdown.Menu>,
    },
    {
        key: id,
        text: id,
        value: name
    },

]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the look of a selection dropdown coupled with the ability to use `<Dropdown.Header />`, try replacing `selection` with `className='selection'`:

```js
<Dropdown className='selection'>
  <Dropdown.Menu>
    <Dropdown.Header content='Header' />
    <Dropdown.Item>{'Item'}</Dropdown.Item>
  </Dropdown.Menu>
</Dropdown>
```